# Help writing an htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'd like an htaccess file that would redirect all pages to my index.php so that I can then parse the url and handle the rest. I just don't know how to write it.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you Google around, you'll find various way to do it. This the way I do it (same as Zend Framework).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```